# POST Content-Length of 167289889 bytes exceeds the limit of 41943040 bytes

Tags: php, reactjs, xampp

I get this message when I upload the pdf file and I changed the following values in php .ini

```
post_max_size=5000M

upload_max_filesize=1000M

max_file_uploads=1000M
```

and In the php file:

```
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '600M');
ini_set('post_max_size', '600M');
header("Content-length: 167289889");
```

But I still get this error:

```
POST Content-Length of 167289889 bytes exceeds the limit of 41943040 bytes
```

php v : 7.4.11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should also check in your apache configuration, in httpd.conf or apache.conf, or some other *.conf files you might be using for the following attribute

```
LimitRequestBody
```

usually it is set to 0 which is unlimited but on your server it might have a limit of its own

Comment: I did not find `LimitRequestBody` in `httpd.conf`, which part of this document can I add `LimitRequestBody`?

Comment: it can go inside server config, virtual host, directory. you can check [apache docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody) as well for more info

Comment: I am glad I helped